# Determine whether the series: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^22^{n+1}}{3^{n}}$ diverges or converges? - I want to check if my reasoning is correct

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I got that the series:

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^22^{n+1}}{3^{n}}$

converges by doing the following:

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^22^{n+1}}{3^{n}}$ = $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^{n+1}}{3^{n}}$

And then I said,

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2$=$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{-2}}$ which converges by p-series test since $p<0$

Then I looked at:

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^{n+1}}{3^{n}}$ = $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(\frac{2}{3})^n$ which is a geometric sequence where $r<1$ hence series converges, hence whole series converges since product of two converging series is still convergent.

Is this the right reasoning? Did I make any assumptions which may be incorrect?

Thank so much for helping ;)

Comment: The equality after "doing the following" is false.

Comment: All kinds of problems with your argument. This isn't the main one, but it's an important one:  $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^2$$ cannot and does not converge.

Comment: you ought to know that this series come from the geometric series through taking derivatives etc. with the ratio $2/3.$ therefore it must converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have used $\sum a_nb_n=\sum a_n\sum b_n$ but that is not true.  Just like $(a+b)(c+d)\not=ac+bd$.  There are a lot of cross terms you have left out.

Instead try to bound the terms, notice that the denominator grows faster.  Break up the denominator and use part of it to control the numerator.

Answer (score 3):

Your series is positive so apply say the $\;n$-th root test:

$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{n^22^{n+1}}{3^n}}=\sqrt[n]{n^2}\cdot\sqrt[n]2\cdot\frac23\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac23<1$$

and thus your series converges.

Comment: Downvoter care to comment? This is a perfectly good argument.

Comment: @SimonS Thanks, but don't worry: I have now a serial downvoter stalker who also downvoted another one of my answers...Oh, well. :)

Comment: Let me compensate ! Good answer, stupid downvoters (I bet that some of them systematically downvote any good answer). $+1$ Cheers ;-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Merci beaucoup, mon ami.

Comment: And another +1 to neutralize the down vote.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thank you . This annoying serial downvoting that many (most?) of us suffer now and then will continue, as in the last years *at least*, until some kind of explanation will be compulsory from the downvoter's side.

Comment: @Timbuc  I had someone give a down vote because they incorrectly claimed that my use of $\int e^{ax}dx=e^{ax}/a$ was not valid for non-real values for $a$.  After I demonstrated the validity, the user actually became offensive.  The moderator actually had to inform this user that he/she was wrong.

Comment: @Dr.MV There you go...but *at least* you knew who (s)he was and you could confront her/him. Mistreatment, abussive lenguage and etc. is nasty but it happens now and then, and giving some reason for a downvote can hlep quit a lot to whoever might be wrong (not once, more than one are...) .

Answer (score 0):

Remember: $\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^j=\frac{1}{1-x}$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$ and $|x|\lt1$. From here: $\sum_{j=1}^\infty jx^{j-1}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$. So: 
$\sum_{j=1}^\infty jx^j=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$. And similarly, $\sum_{j=1}^\infty j^2x^{j-1}=\frac{(1-x)^2+2x(1-x)}{(1-x)^4}=\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^3}$. And finally:
$\sum_{j=1}^\infty j^2x^{j}=\frac{x+x^2}{(1-x)^3}$. Now put: $x=\frac23$. We have: $\sum_{j=1}^\infty j^2(\frac23)^{j}=\frac{\frac23+\frac49}{\frac1{27}}=30$. and finally: $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{j^22^{j+1}}{3^j}=60$